# SignalR multiple hubs and multiple endpoints

Tags: signalr, startup, signalr-hub

I am working on a project with signalr. I am using multiple hubs and multiple endpoints suitable for them.

When I save these endpoints to startup.cs like this, the program runs without errors:

```
endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub2>("/chatHub2");
endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub3>("/chatHub3");
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to do this automatically if the number of hubs increases.

Is there a solution method such as:

```
                foreach (var item in HubList)
                {
                    endpoints.MapHub<HubName>(item);
                }
```

I allready tried that but it didnt work

```
                foreach (var item in HubList)
                {
                    endpoints.MapHub<HubName>(item);
                }
```